# Получу ли я выигрыш от подключения к проекту Delphi DLL из Intel MKL(AVX возможно AVX2)?

Tags: delphi, intel

В программе есть достаточно много  вычислений (тригонометрические функции, скалярное произведение, кватернионы).
Много итераций и на каждой некоторый набор расчетов.

Получу ли я выигрыш от подключения к проекту Delphi DLL из Intel MKL(AVX возможно AVX2)?

Или нет смысла заморачиваться и обойтись средствами самого Delphi?

Answer (score 2):

Мы рассматривали примерно три года назад возможность подключения к некоторым проектам, которые у нас написаны на Delphi, библиотек MKL. В итоге отказались по нескольким причинам:

- необходимо было создавать с нуля интерфейс для Delphi, но не было
  свободных человеко-часов
- существенный выигрыш мог бы быть лишь для
  тех проектов, где использовались Фурье-трансформации и работа с
  большими матрицами, но они у нас как раз реализованы на Фортране/С++,
  к которым MKL подключить не вызывало особых проблем
- какие-то
  заморочки с распространением (каюсь, не помню, какие именно, потому как работой с
  клиентами не интересуюсь)

Моё мнение: для тригонометрии и статистики - смысла нет, для всего остального можно судить лишь достаточно зная много о вашем проекте.

Answer (score 1):

Пример  кода  на дельфи7   подключение  mkl  10.1.1.022
три dll mkl_def.dll mkl_p4m3.dll mkl_intel_thread.dll должны быть в папке с exe.
program GEMMExample;

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{%File 'c:\Program Files\Intel\MKL\10.1.1.022\ia32\bin\mkl_def.dll'}
{%File 'c:\Program Files\Intel\MKL\10.1.1.022\ia32\bin\mkl_p4m3.dll'}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Math;

const
  MKL_DLL = 'c:\Program Files\Intel\MKL\10.1.1.022\ia32\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll';//'mkl_rt.dll'; // Путь к библиотеке MKL

  MatrixSize = 3; // Размер матрицы

type
  TMatrix = array[0..MatrixSize-1, 0..MatrixSize-1] of double;
  PMatrix = ^TMatrix;

var
  A, B, C: TMatrix; // Матрицы
  lda, ldb, ldc: Integer; // Параметры расположения данных в матрицах

  // Функции из библиотеки MKL
  mkl_dgemm: procedure (const TransA, TransB: PAnsiChar; const M, N, K: PInteger;
                        const Alpha: PDouble; const A: PDouble; const lda: PInteger;
                        const B: PDouble; const ldb: PInteger; const Beta: PDouble;
                        const C: PDouble; const ldc: PInteger); cdecl;

procedure LoadMKLProcedures;
var
  MKLHandle: THandle;
begin
  MKLHandle := LoadLibrary(MKL_DLL);
  if MKLHandle = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('Не удалось загрузить билиотеку MKL');

  @mkl_dgemm := GetProcAddress(MKLHandle, 'mkl_blas_dgemm');
  if not Assigned(mkl_dgemm) then
    raise Exception.Create('Не удалось загрузить функцию cblas_dgemm');
end;

procedure FreeMKLProcedures;
begin
  // Выгрузка библиотеки MKL
end;

procedure CalculateMatrixMultiplication;
var
  TransA, TransB: AnsiChar;
  Alpha, Beta: double;
  M, N, K: Integer;
begin
  TransA := 'N'; // Не транспонировать A
  TransB := 'N'; // Не транспонировать B
  M := MatrixSize; // Количество строк в матрице C
  N := MatrixSize; // Количество столбцов в матрице C
  K := MatrixSize; // Общая размерность матриц A и B
  Alpha := 1.0;
  Beta := 0.0;
  
  mkl_dgemm(@TransA, @TransB, @M, @N, @K, @Alpha, @A[0, 0], @lda, @B[0, 0], @ldb, @Beta, @C[0, 0], @ldc);
end;

procedure PrintMatrix(const Matrix: TMatrix);
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to MatrixSize - 1 do
  begin
    for j := 0 to MatrixSize - 1 do
      Write(Format('%8.2f ', [Matrix[i, j]]));
    Writeln;
  end;
  Writeln;
end;

begin
  try
    LoadMKLProcedures;

    lda := MatrixSize; // Количество строк в матрице A
    ldb := MatrixSize; // Количество столбцов в матрице B
    ldc := MatrixSize; // Количество столбцов в матрице C

    // Заполнение матрицы A
    A[0, 0] := 1.0;
    A[0, 1] := 2.0;
    A[0, 2] := 3.0;
    A[1, 0] := 4.0;
    A[1, 1] := 5.0;
    A[1, 2] := 6.0;
    A[2, 0] := 7.0;
    A[2, 1] := 8.0;
    A[2, 2] := 9.0;

    // Заполнение матрицы B
    B[0, 0] := 1.0;
    B[0, 1] := 2.0;
    B[0, 2] := 3.0;
    B[1, 0] := 4.0;
    B[1, 1] := 5.0;
    B[1, 2] := 6.0;
    B[2, 0] := 7.0;
    B[2, 1] := 8.0;
    B[2, 2] := 9.0;
    
    // Вычисление произведения матриц A и B и сохранение результата в C
    CalculateMatrixMultiplication;

    // Вывод результата
    PrintMatrix(C);

    FreeMKLProcedures;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln('Ошибка: ', E.Message);
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Для больших матриц вычисления с помощью Intel MKL и Intel IPP дают иногда прирост в сотню раз по сравнению с Single-thread версиями разных математических библиотек, где не используется SIMD. Прирост производительности в библиотеках Intel  очень существенный. Прочитайте про Delphi-адаптацию этих интелловских библиотек в MtxVec на сайте Dew Research. Там же есть тесты, которые показывают прирост производительности на порядки.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).